# Cannot import local file with pd.read_csv on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, macos

I have a download.csv file stored in a folder "Python" on my local Desktop. Now, I open my Jupyter Notebook locally and want to read this file. I use:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Desktop/Python/download.csv')
df.head()
```

However, it gives me an error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'Desktop/Python/download.csv' does
>   not exist: b'Desktop/Python/download.csv'

What needs to change here?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out: df = pd.read_csv('~/Desktop/Python/download.csv',error_bad_lines=False)

Answer (score 0):

Your `Desktop` is actually located in your user space (your home folder, abbreviated with `~`, which expands to `/Users/<username>`). Replace your path with:

```
~/Desktop/Python/download.csv
```

Like so:

```
df = pd.read_csv('~/Desktop/Python/download.csv')
```

Comment: @wcarhat it did not work. I get a ParseError:  Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 7, saw 2

Comment: @cocoo84hh I would argue that it did work - with this new error it sounds like your code can open the file, but it is a pandas parsing issue, indicating that the initial error is solved. In regards to the `ParseError`, is your CSV formatted correctly?

Answer (score -1):

I agree with @wcarhart. I setup a csv file just like you have @coco84hh but without the error_bad_lines=False). I have df = pd.read_csv('~/Desktop/Python/download.csv')
print(df)

It works.